# Gameobject stops moving or gets stuck when colliding with another GameObject

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, physics

I'm currently making a brick breaker style game. My issue comes when the ball is launched off the pad it gets stuck in between two blocks. I have all the blocks on a "Foreground" layer with an "Order in Layer" set to 0. The Ball is on the "Foreground" with an "Order in Layer" set to 1. But the ball will get stuck and quit moving. I've tried changing the orders of the players and it didn't help. Any thoughts?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with it, I found that I needed to change the collision detection on the Rigidbody2D on the ball to "continuous".